# Grow width of input on focus in angular2

Tags: angular

I am new to angular2, i have an issue with my **input** which has an attribute **autoGorw** it is a custom directive and has two `events` **(focus) and (blur)**, `onFocus()` i want to increase the input size and `onBlur()` i want to decrease the size to its default size, both the `events` been firing and show results in console, but `input` size is not increasing, there isn't any error in my console, i don't know what i am missing.

**Sorry** i tried in `Plunker` for live demo to make you easy to understand, but couldn't made one.

Here is my **code**

**auto-grow.directive.ts**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer} from '@angular/core'

// ElementRef => Gives access to host element
// Renderer => Gives access to modify that element

@Directive({
  selector: '[autoGrow]',
  host:{
    '(focus)' : 'onFocus()',
    '(blur)' : 'onBlur()'
  }
})
export class AutoGrowDirective{
constructor(private el : ElementRef, private renderer : Renderer){       
}    
onFocus(){
    console.log("Triggered !"); // its working upto this line.
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement,'Width','500');
}
onBlur(){
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement,'Width','120');
 }
}
```

**courses.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {AutoGrowDirective} from './auto-grow.directive'

@Component({
  selector:"courses",
  template:`
  <h2>This is Courses component</h2>
  <p>{{ title }}</p>
  <input type="text" autoGrow />
  `,
  directives: [AutoGrowDirective] 
})

export class CoursesComponent{
  title = 'This is the title of Courses Page!';
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {CoursesComponent} from './courses.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>Hello Angular!</h1><courses></courses>',
  directives:[CoursesComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**HTML**

In html inside body i have the **selector**

```
<my-app>Loading Please wait...</my-app>
```

Comment: The `New` button in Plunker editor provides a good Angular2 TS template.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess you are only missing `px` in `'500px'` and `'width'` should be lowercase.

I would do it this way though:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[autoGrow]',
})
export class AutoGrowDirective {
  @HostBinding('style.width.px')
  width:number = 120;

  @HostListener('focus')
  onFocus() {
    this.width=500;
  }

  @HostListener('blur')
  onBlur(){
    this.width = 120;
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ex7g8FcMB6rfSE6EWvOU?p=preview)

Comment: Any explanation for whats wrong in my way of handling `events` ?
btw adding `px` didn't worked.

Comment: Actually it all looks fine to me. You could try `'width'` lowercase.

Comment: I was about to add it to my initial answer but than got doubts that casing matters here :D

Answer (score 3):

Adding 'px' to the width works fine for me.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[autoGrow]',
  host: {
    '(focus)': 'onFocus()',
    '(blur)': 'onBlur()'
  }
})

export class AutoGrowDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {

  }
  onFocus() {
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'width', '200px');
  }
  onBlur() {
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'width', '100px');
  }
}
```